# Error 404 - Not Found Wildfly

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly, cdi

I'm getting error to run XHTML pages in browser.
"Error 404 - not found" when I run in Wildfly 10.0

I've tried everything and still getting error.

This is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>SistemaWeb</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Before I change the standalone-full.xml and setup connection w/ db it worked, after this started getting errors to run in browser.
I'm using JSF 2.2, CDI 1.1, wildfly-10.0.0.Final

I also tried the file jboss-web.xml but doesn't work too.
Someone knows how can I fix it ?

Comment: You have to speak in English.

Comment: English please.

Comment: Sorry... I'm getting error to run XHTML pages w/ wildfly 10.x server, i've tried everything I found here and nothing... Before I do the connection w/ db and change the standalone-full.xml it worked, but now my project connect w/ db successfully and my page xhtml doesn't work... sorry for my english

Comment: I tried this url's : http://localhost:8080/SistemaWeb/produto/form.xhtml and http://localhost:8080/SistemaWeb/faces/produto/form.xhtml

Comment: @PedroRodrigues, can you please edit the question instead of explaining in comments?

Comment: done! appreciate if you help me @M.Prokhorov

Comment: Pedro, its not clear what you're looking for.  While its clear you have an issue, there's no context about the problem.  You may want to include any console logs you see on start up of the server, as well as more information about the application you're deploying.

Comment: It's working now, idk what happened, I just closed the IDE and when I tried again was working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working now, idk what happened, I just closed eclipse and when I tried again was working