# WildFly returns 404 error while same Maven project works fine on TomEE

Tags: maven, jsf, jakarta-ee, http-status-code-404, wildfly

I am trying to make Hello World web application using Eclipse and Java-ee 8, but i can not access .xhtml file, getting 404 error.

It is Maven project.

Before i deploy and run on server, which is WildFly 21.0.2, i do Maven -> Update and Run as -> Maven -> Clean verify.

The server is starting OK, because i can access it at localhost.

Page i am trying to access is index.xhtml, which is in webapp folder next to WEB-INF folder.

There is a similiar question: [Error 404 - Not Found Wildfly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47394753/error-404-not-found-wildfly), but restarting Eclipse did not help.

Page is accessible when i deploy to Apache TomEE 8.0.5 web profile.

When i deploy my java-ee-8 application to WildFly 21.0.2 server (also tried 19.1.0) i can not access xhtml page. I get 404 error code. When i deploy to Apache TomEE 8.0.5 web profile, page is accessible. Both servers are compatible with java-ee-8 and started successfully. No errors in console nor logs.

No configuration were done to the servers, i just added them to Eclipse and started. Same project was deployed. Does anyone know where could be the problem? I want to deploy my app to WildFly, not TomEE.

TomEE starting log, also with accessing the page: https://textuploader.com/185ql

WildFly starting log (nothing in console when trying to access the page): https://textuploader.com/185qc

project structure:

[image: Project structure]

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>vis</groupId>
    <artifactId>eshop-web</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
    version="4.0">
    <display-name>eshop-web</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

index.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color: lightgrey;">
    <h2>Hello World</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

project facets:

[image: Project facets]

Url i am trying to access is this: http://localhost:8080/eshop-web/index.xhtml
Also tried: http://localhost:8080/index.xhtml, http://localhost:8080/webapp/index.xhtml, but still the page can not be found. I think it might be project configuration bug.

Comment: Try http://localhost:8080/eshop-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/index.xhtml

Comment: @volosied The name should be artifact id of that Maven project, but tried and same result. 404 error page. I do not know why it is unaccessible on wildfly while on tomee it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> URL I am trying to access is this: http://localhost:8080/eshop-web/index.xhtml

The context path is wrong.

In case of WildFly, the actually used context path is logged with key `WFLYUT0021`.

The following line is found in your WildFly startup log when searching for this key:

> 23:00:04,727 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 81) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/javaee-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT' for server 'default-server'

So, adjust the URL accordingly: http://localhost:8080/javaee-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/index.xhtml

Comment: Thank you for answer. With that adjusted url i am getting this error: "/index.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource". When i try to go "http://localhost:8080/javaee-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/" (default welcome page should load) i get: Forbidden. Project structure remained same. Any tip for that?

Comment: Either build is dirty, or project structure is actually not the same.